# django model structure for dynamic field

Tags: django, database-design, model

Ok, so I wan't to create a forum app like this:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    section_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200) 
    content = models.TextArea()
```

But, I want 4 types of `Thread` where user can submit text or link or image or link that only contains image. `content` field will change depending on the types. What is the best approach to do this? Do i need to define `SubThread` for each type? or can i define like this:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
THREAD_TYPE = (
    ('text', 'Text'),
    ('link', 'Link'),
        ('imge', 'Image'),
    ('limg', 'Link Image'), 
)

type = models.CharField(max_length = 4, choices = THREAD_TYPE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200) 
if self.type == 'text':
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
# and so on...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely cannot make fields conditional; think about how that would (or wouldn't) work in the database.

Creating a sub-class of Thread for each type is an option, but you would have to use GenericForeignKeys to create a relationship between a Thread sub-class and another model. GenericForeignKeys don't perform as well, if extremely high performance is a major consideration.

Another option would be to define Thread to support all your types (eg has FileField, URLField) and include a field with choices for the different types. Using the type field, you could specify a template to render the item and/or you could filter by type.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want model inheritance. The if statement you have won't work since type won't be set til the model is saved. Think of models as your database design. A column needs to exist for the entire table and not just part of a table. Here's an example of model inheritance:

```
Class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

Class ThreadText(Thread):
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

Class ThreadLink(Thread):
    link = models.URLField()
```

You can also reference the documentation for more information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance